# FabricJS freeDrawing: how to draw inside a specific area

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

With fabricJS I created an object (a circle)  and an backround object  when the canevas is initialised.

My circle will be the "drawing area".

I would like that in case of the mouse is over the circle, the user can draw, and in case of the mouse is out the circle, the user can't.

Here is my code :

```
//create canevas

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

//create background

var imgElement = document.getElementById('img-background');

var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: 0,
  top:  0,
  angle: 0,
  opacity: 1,
  selectable:false
});

canvas.add(imgInstance);

//create drawing area

var drawingArea = new fabric.Circle({ 
  radius: 125, 
  fill: '#f55', 
  top: 75, 
  left: 75,
  selectable: false,
  perPixelTargetFind: true //important
});

canvas.add(drawingArea);

//check when the mouse is inside/outside the drawing area 

drawingArea.on('mouseover',function(e){
  console.log(e.target, 'In circle : I draw');
  canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
});

drawingArea.on('mouseout',function(e){
  console.log(e.target, "Out circle : I can't draw...");
  canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
});
```

And the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <img id="img-background" src="img/background.png" style="display: none;"/>

    <script src="lib/fabric.js"></script>
    <script src="test-stack.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks.